# React - Controlled select form has no default value unless changed

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-redux

I'm using React, Redux with Thunks.

I have a component with a form that has an `input` field, and a `select` tag with multiple options.

When the component loads, the select tag has no value, but will pick up value onChange, since I created an event handler to listen to change.

Ideally the select tag has a default value, which is the first item of a practice api I created.

I tried setting the selected value using `componentDidMount()`, but props is undefined inside there. It's not undefined inside render however...

Below is the code and my attempt

```
class RecipesForm extends Component {
    state = {
        input: '',
        selected: '',
    }

componentDidMount(){ //attempt to use passed props to set the selected value, but props is undefined here..
    const {chefs} = this.props;
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
        this.setState({
            selected: chefs[0].name
        });
    })
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ //attempt to use componentDidUpdate, deleted componentDidMount when this is in use.
    if(this.props !== prevProps){
        const {chefs} = this.props;
        store.subscribe(() => this.setState({
            selected: chefs[0].name
        }))
    }
}

    inputFormChange(event){
        this.setState({input: event.target.value});
    }

    selectedFormChange(event){
        this.setState({selected: event.target.value}); // this works and will give selected a value. But doesn't solve the default value problem
    }

    render(){
      const {chefs} = this.props; //props is defined here, unlike in componentDidMount()
      const {input, selected} = this.state;
      return (
        <div className="form-input">  
          <form onSubmit={this.addRecipe.bind(this)}>
            <input value={input} onChange={this.inputFormChange.bind(this)}/>
            <select value={selected} onChange={this.selectedFormChange.bind(this)}>
              {chefs.map(chef => <option key={chef.id} value={chef.name}>{chef.name}</option> )}
            </select>
            <button>Create</button>      
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      chefs: state.chefs, //tried grabbing this in componentDidMount() as props, to pass as selected value. I would grab chefs[0].name
      recipes: state.recipes,
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(RecipesForm);
```

**Parent Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import RecipesForm from './RecipesForm';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

class Recipes extends Component {
    render(){ //removed a lot of fluff so it's easier to read
        return (
          <div className="content">
            <Provider store={store}>
              <RecipesForm />
            </Provider>
            <div className="recipes-list">
              <ul>{listRecipes}</ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
  }

  export default Recipes;
```

Comment: May I know where did you use the ```RecipeForm``` ccomponent? Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've added the parent component, and also updated the `RecipeForm` component with `mapStateToProps` toward the bottom of the code.

Comment: Did you try putting the subscription to the store in ```componentDidUpdate``` instead of ```componentDidMount```? I suspect that since you are connecting to ```store``` then on initial load you are not getting any props yet.

Comment: I haven't yet.. I just gave it a whirl though. I've barely used componentDidUpdate and subscribe, but I've updated the code to show my attempt. I'm not sure if my attempt makes sense however.

Comment: hey it works! I was using it in the wrong component... but its working now. Should I be doing componentDidUpdate each time I notice that props isn't loaded?

Comment: It might be the best approach when dealing with ```redux``` stores since you are not directly passing props to the ```RecipesForm``` like ```<RecipersForm chefs={//} />``` so you are not getting any props on initial load. Glad to help!

Comment: I was initially passing everything as you mentioned, and everything works just fine. But then I was informed to connect all the components, and now everything breaks because all the components relies on the store being loaded first..